# Swagger wont allow post method to send data to django restAPI

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger

Trying to send data using swagger but POST method is not showing any data input option to send data. why?

here are my views :

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework import status

from .models import Blog
from .serializer import BlogSerializer

@api_view(['GET'])
def get_blogs(request):
    blogs = Blog.objects.all()
    serializer = BlogSerializer(blogs, many=True)
    return Response({
        'Blogs':serializer.data
    }, status.HTTP_200_OK)
    
@api_view(['POST'])
def create_blog(request):
    data = request.data
    serializer = BlogSerializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response({
            'data':serializer.data
        }, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors)
```

Here are my urls :

```
schema_view = get_schema_view(
   openapi.Info(
      title="Blog API",
      default_version='v1',
      description="Test description",
   ),
   public=True,
   permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny,),
)

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("api/", include('app.urls')),
    path('swagger/', schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-swagger-ui'),
    path('redoc/', schema_view.with_ui('redoc', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-redoc'),

]
```

How to send data through post method in swagger?

How to send input data through post method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import **swagger_auto_schema** from **drf_yasg.utils**

user that decorator to give serializer.

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework import status

from .models import Blog
from .serializer import BlogSerializer

from drf_yasg.utils import swagger_auto_schema

@api_view(['GET'])
def get_blogs(request):
    blogs = Blog.objects.all()
    serializer = BlogSerializer(blogs, many=True)
    return Response({
        'Blogs':serializer.data
    }, status.HTTP_200_OK)
    

@swagger_auto_schema(method='POST', request_body=BlogSerializer)
@api_view(['POST'])
def create_blog(request):
    data = request.data
    serializer = BlogSerializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response({
            'data':serializer.data
        }, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors)
```